# Setting the size for an antd select component options list

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, drop-down-menu, antd

The HTML `select` element uses an [attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select#attributes) `size` to determine how many rows should be visible at one time in a scrolling select element.

The code below uses `size="4"` to show 4 options at once.

I would like to know how to get that same functionality using the [Ant Design `Select` component](https://ant.design/components/select/) in a React app.

I've tried setting the attributes `size` and `multiple` but neither work.  I'm open to JavaScript solutions.  Any ideas?

working code:

```html
<select size="4">
  <option id="apple" selected>Apple</option>
  <option id="orange">Orange</option>
  <option id="pineapple">Pineapple</option>
  <option id="banana">Banana</option>
</select>
```

an example code of antd :

```html
const {  Select  } = antd;

const { Option } = Select;

ReactDOM.render(
  <Select
    showSearch
    style={{ width: 200 }}
    placeholder="Search to Select"
    optionFilterProp="children"
    filterOption={(input, option) =>
      option.children.toLowerCase().indexOf(input.toLowerCase()) >= 0
    }
    filterSort={(optionA, optionB) =>
      optionA.children.toLowerCase().localeCompare(optionB.children.toLowerCase())
    }
  >
    <Option value="1">Not Identified</Option>
    <Option value="2">Closed</Option>
    <Option value="3">Communicated</Option>
    <Option value="4">Identified</Option>
    <Option value="5">Resolved</Option>
    <Option value="6">Cancelled</Option>
  </Select>,
  mountNode,
);
```

Comment: anybody has any suggestion ?

Comment: Looking at the [documentation](https://ant.design/components/select/#components-select-demo-tags), the select from Ant doesnt support showing multiple items in the list up-front. The `size` attribute for their `select` is either large, middle or small.

Comment: do you know any way to make it possible, using react ?

Comment: Wouldnt make sense. If you look at the code that gets generated for Ant select, it uses div and span.

Comment: anybody has any suggestion ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The antd `Select` is [built](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/blob/master/components/select/index.tsx) on top of the [rc-select](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rc-select) package instead of the browser's own `select` so just passing `select` attributes won't work.

The component is designed with one section that shows the current selected items and allows the user to type and another section that shows the list of options.  It sounds like you want the list of options to be the only section?  And users just select or deselect by scrolling the list.

I'm only part way there but hopefully this helps.

- `mode="multiple"` allows for multiple selections
- `open={true}` causes the options list to be shown at all times.  Note that this is considered an overlay and will cover other contents, so you'll need to fix some styling.
- `listHeight` is the closest to what you are asking for, but this takes a number of pixels instead of a number of rows.  Each option is 32px at the standard size, so you would want `4 * 32` or `128`.

```
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import { Select } from "antd";
const { Option } = Select;

export default () => (
  <Select
    style={{ width: 200 }}
    placeholder="Hide Me"
    mode="multiple"
    open={true}
    listHeight={128}
  >
    <Option value="1">Not Identified</Option>
    <Option value="2">Closed</Option>
    <Option value="3">Communicated</Option>
    <Option value="4">Identified</Option>
    <Option value="5">Resolved</Option>
    <Option value="6">Cancelled</Option>
  </Select>
);
```

I haven't figured out how to hide the top section with the current selections.  You could do it with CSS but there should be a better way.

Comment: i implemented that in my real code and now i'm getting : Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Key'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Key'.ts(2322)
index.d.ts(12, 5): The expected type comes from property 'value' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & OptionProps & { children?: ReactNode; }'

Comment: Sounds like you are setting an option `key` to a property which is optional but probably should be required.

Comment: at the moment clicked items goes to 'Hide me', how to have them go there one by one and not many ?

Comment: Get rid of `mode="multiple"`?  I just assumed that you wanted to be able to select more than one.

Comment: i wanted to have more than one in drop down menu which this is doing, but when those are clicked goes to 'Hide me' and i dont want user to be able to click many items, just one by one (i mean in 'Hide me' should be one item not more, if user wants more he just unclick it back to down and click another from list to get there)

Comment: any idea how to change width and height of drop down (this specific one without affecting other antd dropdowns?)